# Universal app wont launch in iPad mode?

Tags: iphone, ipad, opengl-es

For some reason my universal app suddenly does not want to launch in fullscreen iPad mode, but it used to do so. I am really not sure what happened.

The iPad target is set to iPhone Devide 3.2 and the iPhone OS deployment target is iPhone OS 3.2 as well. I have set the Targetted device family to iPad.

Yet, the app keep launching into the iPad simulator in a small window indicating it is an iPhone app...

Is there anything else I am missing?

I have tried all kinds of things, but running out of options. Any ideas are appreciated...

It's a native opengl app by the way, not using any .nib file for the display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution was quite simple. Just restart xCode and delete the app's from the iPad. Seems this is the golden rule when things start to behave strangely...